# How to select all WebView content using Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, select, webview

Note: This is **Android-specific** question (i.e. [methods using Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript/665577#665577) seem not to be applicable for Android).

Is it possible to use Javascript to **select** all WebView content?

Also note that I am asking about "select" only, not necessarily copy to clipboard.

If your method happens to do both select & copy, that is good, too, but it's not mandatory. All I need right now is a way to select **all** WebView content (as if I am about to copy it), using Javascript.

If this is possible, can you post sample Javascript code that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that might help [Extracting HTML from a WebView](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/extracting-html-from-a-webview/)